# Spring Social Configuration Issue

Tags: spring

I have used social:jdbc-connection-repository in an effort to configure SocialAuthenticationFilter, but its seems not to be recognized by Spring as it complains userConnectionRepository has not been defined. I am using maven 1.1.0.M4

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="userConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg index="3" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
   <property name="signupUrl" value="/user/register"/>
</bean>
```

Further, can I know how to define userConnectionRepository and connectionFactoryLocator in XML without using social:jdbc-connection-repository?

Comment: Can you please post your definition of userConnectionRepository?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the below code :

```
 @Bean
 @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository(){
    return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(datasource, connectionFactoryLocator(),textEncryptor);

    }
```